# Reference a library in Xcode for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am used to Visual studio, I have class library projects that I reference in my web sites or windows applications. Using class libraries allows me to create common functionalities, utilities once and use them over and over again.

How do I do this with Xcode and iPhone App development?

I am looking for some details on how to create the library, where to stores the files and how to reference in my App. That is if it is possible.

I am very very new to Mac and Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a Static Library for iPhone App](http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/02/08/creating-a-static-library-for-iphone.html)

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone, you need to create a 'static library' target. This will build your code into a .a file which will then be integrated directly into your iPhone application.

Answer (score 0):

http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/

This way has worked for me. If you need to use xibs or other non-compilable resource files in the framework, look at the embedded framework section.